# Data not displayed in UICollectionviewcell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am Creating one UIImageview and two UILables in UICollectionviewcell.my Data stored in NSArray and formate is NSDictionary ,key and values. but data was not showned in UICollectionviewCell. This is my Code Please check my Code.

```
//---- ItemviewController ---//
  mensarrayimages = @[ @{ @"description": @"Mens Fashion",
                      @"articles": @[ @{ @"image": @"SlimFit.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"Brown.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"Black.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"Brown.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"SlimFit.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"SlimFit.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"Brown.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"Black.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"Brown.jpg" },
                                      @{ @"image": @"SlimFit.jpg" }
                                      ],
                               @"itemname":  @[ @{ @"name": @"SlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"BrownSlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"SlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"BrownSlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"SlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"SlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"BrownSlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"SlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"BrownSlimFit"},
                                                @{ @"name": @"SlimFit"}
                                                ],
                            @"itemprice": @[ @{ @"price": @"1499"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1599"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1399"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1599"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1499"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1499"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1599"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1399"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1599"},
                                             @{ @"price": @"1499"}
                                             ],
                            },
];
//---UITableview--///

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [mensarrayimages count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //return [modaldatabase.imagesArray count];
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   // static NSString *cellidentifier =@"cell";


        MensCell *cell = [itemTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MensCell"];
        //------ NSDictinary------

         cellData = [mensarrayimages objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
         priceData = [mensarrayimages objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
         priceData1 = [mensarrayimages objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

       //--- NSARRAY---

        NSArray *articleData = [cellData objectForKey:@"articles"];
        NSArray *itemnamedata = [priceData objectForKey:@"itemname"];
        priceArr = [priceData1 objectForKey:@"itemprice"];

       [cell setCollectionData:articleData];
       [cell setCollectionData1:itemnamedata];
       [cell setCollectionData2:priceArr];

       return cell;

}

//------ UICollectionview ---///
//-- CollectionviewController--//

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.collectionarray count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CollectionCell1 *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *cellDataname = [self.collectionarray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",cellDataname);
    NSDictionary *cellDataimage = [self.arrayImage objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",cellDataimage);
    NSDictionary *cellDataprice = [self.arrayprice objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",cellDataprice);

    cell.ItemImageName.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellDataimage objectForKey:@"image"]]];
    cell.ItemName.text = [cellDataname objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.ItemPrice.text = [cellDataprice objectForKey:@"price"];

    return cell;
}
```

UITableviewcell -> UICollectionviewController -> UICollectionviewCell .

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a vague question. However, maybe the UI structure is a little off?

```
UITableView -> UICollectionViewController -> UICollectionViewCell
```

That is something I have yet to see someone attempt. From what I can see here, you should backtrack to using a simple UITableView or UICollectionView but not both at the same time. Use either:

```
UITableViewController -> UITableView -> UITableViewCell
```

or

```
UICollectionViewController -> UICollectionView -> UICollectionViewCell
```

I would suggest going with the first since UITableViews are generally easier to code and maintain